# agregar un parent node entre nodes php

Tags: php, xml

Tengo el siguiente xml y quisiera agregar debajo de MedioPago dos nodos iguales, sin embargo el debajo del nodo MedioPago existe mas elementos, lo que quiero es agregar solo dos nodos mas en el campo de MedioPago no son children sino parent ambos

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user_info>
<Clave>1234</Clave>
<CodigoActividad>010101</CodigoActividad>}
<NumeroConsecutivo>12341234</NumeroConsecutivo>
<FechaEmision>2020202020</FechaEmision>
<MedioPago>99</MedioPago>
</user_info>
```

Comment: prueba con un split, lo añades y lo vuelves a pegar

Answer (score 0):

Usa [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php) para manejarlo en forma muy similar a Javascript:

- Teniendo el texto, creas el objeto y cargas el contenido XML
- `$xml->documentElement` es el punto de partida para obtener cualquier dato
- Busca el elemento deseado por nombre de etiqueta.
- Vas a obtener una colección y hay que especificar que se desea solo el primero `->item(0)`
- Debes clonar el elemento tantas veces como necesites agregar copias
- Asignas valor a cada elemento copiado y lo agregas al documento

```
$str = <<<EOT
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user_info>
<Clave>1234</Clave>
<CodigoActividad>010101</CodigoActividad>}
<NumeroConsecutivo>12341234</NumeroConsecutivo>
<FechaEmision>2020202020</FechaEmision>
<MedioPago>99</MedioPago>
</user_info>
EOT;

// Inicializar Elemento y cargar XML desde cadena
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($str);

// Obtener el elemento a copiar
$item = $xml->documentElement->getElementsByTagName('MedioPago')->item(0);

// Crear dos copias
$copia1 = $item->cloneNode();
$copia2 = $item->cloneNode();

// Asignar valor a las copias
$copia1->nodeValue = $item->nodeValue;
$copia2->nodeValue = $item->nodeValue;

// Agregar a contenedor
$item->parentNode->appendChild($copia1);
$item->parentNode->appendChild($copia2);

// Guardar y mostrar
$resultado = $xml->saveXML();
var_dump($resultado);
```

Resultado:

```
test.php:35:string '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user_info>
<Clave>1234</Clave>
<CodigoActividad>010101</CodigoActividad>}
<NumeroConsecutivo>12341234</NumeroConsecutivo>
<FechaEmision>2020202020</FechaEmision>
<MedioPago>99</MedioPago>
<MedioPago>99</MedioPago>
<MedioPago>99</MedioPago>
</user_info>
' (length=274)
```